# Switching between abstract class implementations as DataContext of a view WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am building a WPF MVVM application, representing a Task Manager -> adding tasks and keeping track of whether they're done.

I have an abstract class `TaskBase` and 2 example tasks -> `ToDoTask` and `Reminder`, which both inherit from `TaskBase` but have a few more properties.

I have implemented an `ITaskRepository` which keeps all the tasks and has functionalities such as Get, Add, Edit and Remove task.

The main idea of the application is to display the tasks and have the possibility to add a task. Whenever the user clicks on the Add button, a new window appears with a `ComboBox`, which is bound to an enum `TaskType` (with currently 2 values - Reminder and ToDoTask), a `ContentControl`, which is bound to a property of type `TaskBase`, whose data is supposed to be filled, and an `IRelayCommand` which adds the task to the repository.

Visual:
[image: AddTaskView]

```
public class AddTaskViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private TaskType selectedTaskType;
    private TaskBase task;

    public TaskType SelectedTaskType
    {
        get => selectedTaskType;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref selectedTaskType, value);

            switch (selectedTaskType)
            {
                case TaskType.ToDoTask:
                    Task = new ToDoTask();
                    break;
                case TaskType.Reminder:
                    Task = new Reminder();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public TaskBase Task 
    { 
        get => task;
        set => SetProperty(ref task, value); 
    }

    public IRelayCommand AddTaskCommand { get; set; }
}
```

`AddTaskViewModel` is a property inside the `MainViewModel` and the `AddTaskCommand` is actually set there.

In the `AddTaskView.xaml`, the `DataContext` of the `ContentControl` is set to `Task` and its style has triggers, so whenever the user changes the selected task type, the content of the `ContentControl` changes accordingly.

Everything works great and does what it is supposed to do, but what I am concerned about is this part of the code:

```
public TaskType SelectedTaskType
{
    get => selectedTaskType;
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref selectedTaskType, value);

        switch (selectedTaskType)
        {
            case TaskType.ToDoTask:
                Task = new ToDoTask();
                break;
            case TaskType.Reminder:
                Task = new Reminder();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to make everything as extensible as possible, but if I add another class, inheriting from `TaskBase` and would like to more quickly adapt everything to it, I would also have to modify this switch case (breaking the Open/Closed principle).

Is there a better approach I could take when building the app architecture?

Comment: You can have an `ITaskFactory` which creates the choosen task instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating instances based on an argument. This always requires a sort of parameter checking.
This pattern introduces two problems: *1)* the explicit dependency on concrete types and implementation details like constructor parameters and *2)* the parameter type `switch`. Both compromise extensibility.

Problem *1)* is solved by moving the instantiation code out of the type that depends on those new instances.
Usually you use the *Factory Method* pattern or *Abstract Factory* pattern. This means instantiation is moved either to the type itself or a factory.
This doesn't solve problem *2)*: the other type that is now responsible for the dynamic instantiation still has to check its parameters in order to decide which type to instantiate.

Problem *2)* is solved by introducing a sort of hash table.

The *Abstract Factory* pattern is best because it avoids the need to pass the hash table around the application.
For example, combining both solutions into a `TaskFactory` could look as follows:

```cs
interface ITaskFactory
{
  // Does not throw if creation fails
  bool TryCreate(TaskType taskType, out TaskBase newTask);

  // Throws if creation fails
  TaskBase Create(TaskType taskType);
}

class TaskFactory : ITaskFactory
{
  public TaskFactory(IReadOnlyDictionary<TaskType, Func<TaskBase>> productFactoryTable) 
    => this.ProductFactoryTable = productPool;

  public TaskBase Create(TaskType taskType) 
  {
    Func<TaskBase> taskFactory = this.ProductFactoryTable[taskType];
    return taskFactory.Invoke();
  }

  public bool TryCreate(TaskType taskType, out TaskBase newTask) 
  {
    bool canCreate = this.ProductFactoryTable.TryGetValue(taskType, out Func<TaskBase> taskFactory);
    newTask = taskFactory?.Invoke();
    return canCreate;
  }

  private IReadOnlyDictionary<TaskType, Func<TaskBase>> ProductFactoryTable { get; }
}
```

You could use this class directly or hide it behind the existing `ITaskRepository`. Because there is already a specialized repository class, I would extend its API to allow creation of `TaskBase` instances:

**ITaskRepository.cs**

```cs
interface ITaskRepository 
{
  TaskBase CreateNewTask(TaskType taskType);
  
  /* Existing API */
}
```

**TaskRepository.cs**

```cs
class TaskRepository : ITaskRepository
{
  private ITaskFactory TaskFactory { get; }

  public TaskRepository(ITaskFactory taskFactory)
  {
    this.TaskFactory = taskFactory;
  }

  public TaskBase CreateNewTask(TaskType taskType)
    => this.TaskFactory.Create(taskType);

  /* Existing API implementation */
}
```

### Usage example

**AddTaskViewModel.cs**

```cs
class AddTaskViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public AddTaskViewModel(ITaskRepository taskRepository)
  {
    this.TaskRepository = taskRepository;
  }

  private void OnSelectedTaskTypeChanged()
    => this.SelectedTask = this.TaskRepository.CreateNewTask(this.SelectedTaskType);

  public ITaskRepository TaskRepository { get; }
  public TaskBase SelectedTask { get; set; }

  private TaskType selectedTaskType;
  public TaskType SelectedTaskType
  {
    get => this.selectedTaskType;
    set
    {
      this.selectedTaskType = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
      OnSelectedTaskTypeChanged();
    }
  }
}
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
  private void OnApplicationStarting(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
  {
    // This is the only place that will require modification 
    // when new TaskBase implementations are added 
    // (of course the TaskType enum and the UI will require modification too)
    var productFactoryTable = new Dictionary<TaskType, Func<TaskBase>>()
    {
      { TaskType.Reminder, () => new Reminder() },
      { TaskType.ToDoTask, () => new ToDoTask() },
    };
    var taskFactory = new TaskFactory(productFactoryTable)
    var taskRepository = new TaskRepository(taskfactory);
    var addTaskViewModel = new AddTaskViewModel(taskRepository);
    var mainViewModel = new ManViewModel(addTaskViewModel);
    var mainWindow = new MainWindow(mainViewModel);

    mainWindow.Show();
  }
}
```